Springdoc OpenAPI -No operations defined in spec
I am migrating my project from swagger to springdoc openapi and seeing the following error when I use swagger-ui/index.html endpoint:

My POM file:
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
      <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
    </dependency>

Configurations:
@Bean
    public GroupedOpenApi api() {
      return GroupedOpenApi.builder().group("Test")
        .packagesToScan("com.test")
        .pathsToMatch("/api.\*").build();
    }

@Bean
    public OpenAPI channelApiInfo() {
      Contact contact = new Contact();
      contact.setName("TestAPIs");
      contact.setEmail("test.com");
         return new OpenAPI()
           .info(new Info().title("Test Service")
           .description("This is a test service.")
           .contact(contact));
    }

Endpoint config:
    @Operation(summary = "Test API", description = "This is a test api")
    @ApiResponses(value = {
    @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "Success"),
    @ApiResponse(responseCode = "400", description = "ID is invalid")})
      public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity\<Resource\> getId(
    @Parameter(description = IdDesc, required = true) @PathVariable final String id) {
    //Implementation
    }


You can review the openApi documentation, point number 9 talks about the migration and you can have a better idea.
https://springdoc.org/#migrating-from-springfox
If you have only one Docket — remove it and instead add properties to your application.properties:
springdoc.packagesToScan=package1, package2
springdoc.pathsToMatch=/v1, /api/balance/**

This worked for me, thank you! I had to also add swagger-annotations dependency to recognize the new annotations along with springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui
